# Assigning role to users upon Registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, roles

I'm very new to c#. I'm trying to create a web application which will assign the user a "User" role automatically upon registration using identity 2.0 and MVC5.

```
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I run the above code I am getting the following error once registration has been completed

```
     Role User does not exist.

     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

     Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Role User does not exist.

      Source Error: 


      Line 156:                if (result.Succeeded)
      Line 157:                {
      Line 158:                    result = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");
      Line 159:                   
      Line 160:                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user,                isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the role first. Add this to your Startup.Auth.cs file

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("User"));
```

If you are not using `ApplicationDbContext` for identity, supply the context you are using to `RoleStore` constructor.